# Forward slash htaccess break style sheet

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm terrible with htaccess and regular expressions so this isn't really my thing. Im working on a navigation system that allows the user to select links like so

```
<a href="home/">Home</a>
<a href="about/">About</a>
```

using this piece of htaccess I found somewhere on the internet

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Ok,so basically this allows me to rewrite my urls, however when i add the / it breaks my style and when i look at the source it adds the name of the link into the url like so.

```
http://localhost/current-project/index/css/default.css
or
http://localhost/current-project/about/css/default.css
```

when it should be:

```
http://localhost/current-project/css/default.css
```

Anyway to only make it rewrite php files?

Comment: Can you show the html code where you are referencing the css files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your stylesheets and images using a path like `/css/default.css` rather than just `css/default.css`. Alternatively, consider using a base tag, like
`<base href="http://localhost/current-project/" />`. This will make sure everything will link correctly, but then you have to remember to be careful with relative URLs as they will be relative to the base and not the current folder.

Comment: Was thinking the same. @JohnCrossley - Use absolute paths (relative to your host) in your `<script`, `<style`, `<a`, etc.. tags.